# Structure passed by value slow down the computer working when compared to structure passed by reference? True or false?

Tags: c++

when passed by value -
void func(Object o);
calling -
func(a);

When passed by reference -
void func(Object& o);
Calling -
func(a);

Comment: "slow down" is a bit much... How big is that structure?

Comment: Probably the first question of any programming book try to teach pointers.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314010/should-small-simple-structs-be-passed-by-const-reference?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Slower or faster?

is maybe the wrong question.

---

Your reference example is one place where an experienced programmer would probably use

```
void foo (const T& t);
```

(Despite the 'premature optimization' it might imply.)

The const qualifier is documenting that the reference is input (only) to the function foo().

So I guess I should ask you to clarify if "const T&" is what you mean.

---

Recommendation - worry less about performance, spend your time making the code work correctly, and write to communicate to your reader.  Then, when time and energy and interest (and your supervisor) allows, test ... prove any hoped for performance gains.

Comment: @Nannypatel - Does passing a 'const T&' vs 'T' affect the compiler?  Not sure how to measure that.  How often do you compile?   Does passing a 4 byte (compiler dependent) 'const T&' perform better than copying a n-K byte struct?  probably.  But will the difference be noticeable by the user?  When done once, probably not.  When done 10^6 times, maybe, depending on all the other stuff going on.  I.E. it depends ...   I know. I know.  You want a simple answer from people who should know.   With practice, you will form your own opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the size of the struct.

- If the struct is small (e.g. a few ints), then it's usually faster to pass by value.
- If the struct is much larger than that it's almost always better to pass by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a reference means copying a pointer (8 bytes in 64 bits machines). If the structure you want to pass is bigger than a pointer, then it will be slower since it need to copy more data.

Comment: A structure (object or struct) has an address in memory. If you choose to pass the parameter by reference, you'll be copying this address to the function.

Comment: Which is better? Call by value or reference in structure?

Comment: Depends on what your function does. Remember that passing the reference means that if you modify the structure inside the function, it will be modified in memory. In terms of speed, passing by reference is better if the structure is bigger than a pointer. But if your function modifies the structure and you don't want it to do so, then your best choice is to pass by value